# Honda Accord: ABS Sensor hasn't fixed problem

Tags: abs

first post on here, so answers gratefully received.

I have a Honda Accord 2006, ABS sensor line was ruined by flapping tyre in a blowout on the motorway (freeway).

I ordered a new sensor (non-Honda) and fitted it after *a lot* of fighting to get the old one out, and the ABS, VSA and Warning lights went out.  I took it in for it's MOT test (UK roadworthiness test for those abroad), and the ABS light came back on as I went.

Initially, I figured that this almost certainly meant one of the following:

- Grit/rust on the sensor ring from after the new installation.
- Sensor isn't in place properly.
- Damage to the sensor in some way.

Instead of the MOT, I had the garage review the whole ABS system, and they tell me no problem with the sensor ring, sensor is in, and the issue is probably behind the wiring harness.

I think they haven't so much as taken the sensor out, much less looked at the sensor ring etc., and that I either need another new sensor, or the sensor hole needs further cleaning.

What do people think?  I'm torn between spending another evening taking a look at it, and just taking it direct to an electrician.  I'm limited on time, but equally, keen to fix it myself if I can.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to do is a diagnostic scan and find out why the car has turned on it's ABS light.  This may give you guidance on the fault.  Also, worth having the fault codes cleared and take the car for a test drive.  It may be that the fault doesn't re-occur or that it reports a different fault after being cleared.

Chances are, if the brakes look visually okay to a mechanic, that a dedicated auto electrician may get to the root of the problem quicker (and cheaper) than a traditional mechanic.

Comment: Thanks.  Diagnostic reads that the FR ABS sensor is disconnected.

Comment: @Seej - If the system is reading as "disconnected" the problem is with the wiring and not the sensor, unless the sensor has no continuity at all, which can easily be checked with a multimeter set to measure resistance. If there's resistance, but continuity, check the wiring on the vehicle side of the circuit.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yeah, I thought as much.  In fitting the sensor, the cable has to be fitted into channels that bolt to the wheel arch etc., so I think there's some posibility that the wire is just damaged/torn from my (maybe a little poor) workmanship.

Comment: @Seej - I would bet there are tests you could run to check continuity of the wiring. You'd probably have to trace the wires back to the ABS computer to find a point to test from.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I thought about multimeter testing the sensor initially, comparing it to the standard resistance, but I've not had chance